# Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, amazon-rds, database-deadlocks

I am sending bulk invitations to my users from my website. For that I am passing comma separated string which contains emails to my stored procedure in mysql. In this stored procedure one while loop parses each email (using substring() separated by comma) and checks existing database and then Insert to table if it's absent or generates email link with guid if that email already exists. The process is working fine for small batches (eg. below 200-250 emails), but if batch is larger (250+ emails), whole process stucks and next requests are getting deadlock errors (original error is: "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"). So, I have planned to do a while loop at my javascript or c# file (programming language file) and send each email to store procedure. 
In above scenario number of mysql connections would increase and max connection error might be occurre.

So, I want to ask, what is the best method to do this kind of jobs with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I think giving emails to procedure one at a time is a correct solution yet you don't need to make new connection or even new request for each item. Most languages support prepared statement execution ([and here's the answer on how to use them in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662794/mysql-will-using-prepared-statements-to-call-a-stored-procedure-be-any-faster-w)).

The deadlocks in turn can be cause by your own code but without a snips of it it's hard to tell. Maybe your procedure isn't re-entrant or the data can be accessed from some other location.

Comment: thanks @kworr, but it is performing very slow, and it is throwing error for deadlock.

Comment: Actually prepared statements are much faster then regular ones because you don't need to parse SQL each time. It can be even faster then splitting the whole string in mysql.

Comment: I have posted another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091968/deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-transaction-2nd-try) for your reference. please guide me. thanks