# Deadlock while inserting records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, amazon-rds, database-deadlocks

I have application which is sending bulk invitation to my users. for that I am inserting thousands of records in a one table. My stored procedure accept comma separated string from user as a parameter, and then split by comma and parse each email from that string in a loop, and insert individual email as a record in the table.

The main problem is when multiple users when send their request to this stored procedure at the same time, mysql throwing "dead lock" error, because each user connecting with different connection to mysql. 
So, my question is what is the proper solution to do this kind of task? or this is problem with my database configuration? I am using Amazon RDS (mysql) large instance. and my user can send 2000 emails at a time. and one more thing, I am not using transaction... commit... rollback.

I have posted this use case as a question earlier, but I didn't get any proper answer. Here is that links :

1) [Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089203/deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-transaction)

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091968/deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-transaction-2nd-try

Thanks

Comment: It seems that the procedure produces a dynamic query: `INSERT INTO InviteMst ( .... ) VALUES ( 1st rec ), ( 2nd rec ) .... ( Nth rec)`, is that correct ? Please show a structure of table `InviteMst`. Please show foreign constraints, if any. Please also show all triggers fired before/after insert on this table, if any.

Comment: thanks @kordirko, yes, you are right. I have inserting records in a bulk. there is no trigger on this table. 3 foreign key relation with UserMst (about 50000 records), LoginMst (about 1500000 records) & DomainMst (50 records) tables.